# IO action nested in other monads not executing

Tags: haskell, io-monad

I have a

```
foobar :: IO (ParseResult [(String,String)])
```

ParseResult is a monad defined here: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/haskell-src-exts-1.13.5/docs/Language-Haskell-Exts-Parser.html#t:ParseResult

I want to take those strings and write them to a `LaTeXT m ()` defined in https://hackage.haskell.org/package/HaTeX-3.17.1.0/docs/Text-LaTeX-Base-Writer.html

Running this function results in no file being created.

```
writeReport2 :: [Char] -> IO (ParseResult (IO ()))
writeReport2 name = do x <- foobar
                       return $ do y <- x
                                   return $ do z <- (execLaTeXT.docAndGraph) y
                                               renderFile fileName z
  where
    fileName = name ++ ".tex"
```

However the code:

```
writeReport :: t -> LaTeXT IO a -> IO ()
writeReport name report = createLatex >>= renderFile fileName
  where
    createLatex = execLaTeXT report
    fileName = "AAAAA" ++ ".tex"


testFoo = [(" | HaskellExample Example File\n | Two examples are given below:\n\n >>> fib 10\n 55\n\n >>> putStrLn \"foo\\nbar\"\n foo\n bar ","fib :: Int -> Int"),("\n | This is a thing: ","fib = undefined"),("\n | This is a thing:\n","fibar :: String -> Float")]

itWorks = writeReport "AAAA.txt" $ docAndGraph testFoo
```

Will create a new file.

Both sets of code type check.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I could get `writeReport2` working without modification.

I think what might have been your problem is the **nested IO action** in the return value of `writeResport2`!

In order to *flatten* the nested `IO` actions, I had to use the function [`join :: Monad m => m (m a) -> m a` from `Control.Monad`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-8.2/base-4.9.1.0/Control-Monad.html#v:join):

```
main :: IO ()
main = join $ fromParseResult <$> writeReport2 "test"
```

Here is my complete code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

module Main where

import           Language.Haskell.Exts.Parser
import           Text.LaTeX.Base.Writer
import           Text.LaTeX
import           Data.String
import           Control.Monad

foobar :: IO (ParseResult [(String, String)])
foobar = return (ParseOk testFoo)

testFoo = [ ( " | HaskellExample Example File\n | Two examples are given below:\n\n >>> fib 10\n 55\n\n >>> putStrLn \"foo\\nbar\"\n foo\n bar "
            , "fib :: Int -> Int"
            )
          , ("\n | This is a thing: ", "fib = undefined")
          , ("\n | This is a thing:\n", "fibar :: String -> Float")
          ]

docAndGraph :: Monad m => [(String, String)] -> LaTeXT m ()
docAndGraph x = do
    documentclass [] article
    document $
        raw (fromString (show x))

writeReport2 :: [Char] -> IO (ParseResult (IO ()))
writeReport2 name = do
    x <- foobar
    return $ do
        y <- x
        return $ do
            z <- (execLaTeXT . docAndGraph) y
            renderFile fileName z
  where
    fileName = name ++ ".tex"

main :: IO ()
main = join $ fromParseResult <$> writeReport2 "test"
```

Loading into GHCi:

```
$ stack ghci
io-action-nested-in-other-monads-not-executing-0.1.0.0: initial-build-steps (exe)
Configuring GHCi with the following packages: io-action-nested-in-other-monads-not-executing
Using main module: 1. Package `io-action-nested-in-other-monads-not-executing' component exe:io-action-nested-in-other-monads-not-executing with main-is file: /home/sven/dev/stackoverflow-questions/io-action-nested-in-other-monads-not-executing/src/Main.hs
GHCi, version 8.0.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loaded GHCi configuration from /home/sven/.ghc/ghci.conf
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( /home/sven/dev/stackoverflow-questions/io-action-nested-in-other-monads-not-executing/src/Main.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: Main.
Loaded GHCi configuration from /tmp/ghci22616/ghci-script
```

And running it:

```
λ main
```

Creates this file:

```
$ cat test.tex 
\documentclass{article}\begin{document}[(" | HaskellExample Example File\n | Two examples are given below:\n\n >>> fib 10\n 55\n\n >>> putStrLn \"foo\\nbar\"\n foo\n bar ","fib :: Int -> Int"),("\n | This is a thing: ","fib = undefined"),("\n | This is a thing:\n","fibar :: String -> Float")]\end{document}%
```

I know it is not the scope of the question, but you could circumvent the nested `IO` if you want, by doinf this, for example:

```
writeReport3 :: [Char] -> IO ()
writeReport3 name = do
    let fileName = name ++ ".tex"
    x <- foobar
    case x of
      ParseOk y -> do
        z <- execLaTeXT (docAndGraph y)
        renderFile fileName z
      ParseFailed _ _ ->
        return ()

main :: IO ()
main = writeReport3 "test"
```

Comment: Do you happen to have an explanation as to why the nesting causes the IO action to not perform?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42404258/why-will-a-io-nested-in-other-monads-not-execute-is-there-a-way-to-force-them-t/42404828#42404828