# Why will a IO nested in other monads not execute? Is there a way to force them to?

Tags: haskell, monads

This is a follow up of my last question.
[IO action nested in other monads not executing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42382396/io-action-nested-in-other-monads-not-executing)

The solution to that question was to remove some of the monads, and that allowed the IO action to execute.

Why did I need to unnest the monads? Is there a way to execute the IO without unnesting?

**Note**: This is a *what-if* more than it is a question about good or bad practice.

Comment: I think this question is "help me understand IO in haskell" which is too broad imo. My brief but cryptic answer is: you don't get to "execute" IO, only the caller of `main` gets to (whose magic elves are the only ones who know how to get inside an `IO` value and make it go). The API you're given for IO is `>>=` and `return` and that's about all there is too it.

Comment: "a IO" doesn't execute. The computer executes the IO. More specifically, the computer executes the IO called `main`. If your IO isn't part of `main` then the computer won't execute it.

Comment: Here's a brainteaser: what does `main = print (length [print "hi", print "bye"])` print?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Perhaps it would help to think of `IO` as `type IO a = World -> (a, World)`; that is, a function that takes as its only parameter the current state of your computer and returns a new state along with some value `a`. This is not too dissimilar from the actual implementation of `IO` in GHC internals, so hopefully we can forgive the (abject) method of communicating by analogy here.

So `readFile :: FilePath -> IO String`, for example, becomes `readFile :: FilePath -> World -> (a, World)`.

And `main :: IO ()` is really `main :: World -> ((), World)`.

What this means, however, is that values with type `IO _` are inert. They are just functions! Functions cannot do anything until they are given a value; in our case, the value the function wants is a `World` object, which we have *no way of constructing*. Therein lies the beauty of IO in Haskell: we can build up an `IO` action by using the monadic operators we know and love (return, bind) but it cannot do anything until the runtime passes in the `World` object.

Which means that any `IO` action we build that isn't threaded through `main` won't be executed.

So, with `foobar :: [Char] -> IO [IO ()]`, we can certainly observe the return value:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  ios <- foobar "string"
  print "goodbye"
```

But it's not until we deconstruct `ios` and bind the internal `IO` values that those actions receive the `World` they desire:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  ios <- foobar
  ios !! 0
  ios !! 1
  ios !! 2
  ...
  print "goodbye"
```

Or, for short,

```
main = do
  ios <- foobar
  sequence ios
  print "goodbye"
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

Let's begin with a slightly different example. As you know, a `String` is a list of `Char`:

```
GHCi> :set +t
GHCi> "Mississippi"
"Mississippi"
it :: [Char]
```

A list of `Strings` is a list of lists of `Char`; that is, a `[[Char]]`:

```
GHCi> group "Mississippi"
["M","i","ss","i","ss","i","pp","i"]
it :: [[Char]]
```

`group "Mississippi"` is a `[[Char]]`, and I don't want it handled as a `[Char]` -- that would defeat the point of using `group`.

An `IO a` value is, for most purposes, a value just like any other, and so analogous considerations apply. To give a concrete ([and realistic](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/reactive-banana-1.1.0.1/docs/Control-Event-Handler.html)) example, suppose we have a function with this type...

```
(KeyCode -> IO ()) -> IO (IO ())
```

... which registers event handlers for a key press event in a GUI. The idea is that you call the function with a `KeyCode -> IO ()` argument, which specifies what should happen in response to the key press, and run the the resulting `IO (IO ())` so that the your chosen `KeyCode -> IO ()` handler becomes active. The *inner* `IO ()` *produced by* the `IO (IO ())` action, however, serves a different purpose: it unregisters the event handler, and it is meant to be used at a later point of the application at your discretion -- perhaps never. In this case, you definitely do not want to run the inner action immediately after the outer one!

Summing it up, an `IO (IO a)` is an `IO` action that, when run, produces another `IO` action, which you may or may not want to run as well.

P.S.: As sheyll mentioned [in the other Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42382982/2751851), `join` can be used to flatten a nested `IO` action, or any other nested monadic value. Incidentally, lists also have a `Monad` instance. What do you think `join (group "Mississippi")` will do?

Answer (score 0):

Well ... you ask the question:

> Why did I need to unnest the monads? Is there a way to execute the IO without unnesting?

Well, let me put it as blunt as possibe: **Unnesting** or **`join`ing** how we call it in Haskell-land, is not just yet another monad combinator, it is **a holy special moand thing** that differentiates `Monad`s from `Functor` and `Applicative`!

Yes, that totally means that the `Monad` type class could have been designed with a **`join`** method instead of **`>>=`**.

Actually *unnesting* and *binding* **are two different perspectives for the same thing**!

Let me spoil the rest of this post:

```
join = (>>= id)
```

... and:

```
(ma >>= amb) = join (amb <$> ma)
```

Let's *prove* them equal by showing that we can make a `join` of `>>=` and vice versa.

### Making `join` from `>>=`

Ok now `join = (>>= id)` in more detail:

```
join mmx = do mx <- mmx
              x <- mx
              return x
```

and then:

```
join mmx = do mx <- mmx
              mx
```

and now with **`bind`** aka **`>>=`**:

```
join mmx = mmx >>= id
```

and point free using *sections*:

```
join = (>>= id)
```

### Making `>>=` from `join`

Now the other way around, it is harder, we need that fact that every `Monad` is a `Functor` too.

Remember what `>>=` actaully **do**es (pun intended):

```
ma >>= amb = do a <- ma
                amb a
```

We know that `amb` is a function of type `a -> m b`, the idea is to use `fmap` which has `(c -> d) -> m c -> m d`, if we `fmap` `amb` we get an expression `fmap amb` then `c` becomes `a` and `d` becomes `m b` and `m c -> m d` hence becomes `m a -> m (m b)`!

Now we are thrilled: `m (m b)` just screams `join`, we only need to put in the `m a` which we can do with normal application:

```
ma >>= amb = do mb <- fmap amb ma
                mb
```

and this is something we saw in the previous section:

```
join mmb = do mb <- mmb
              mb
```

with `mmb == fmap amb ma`

```
ma >>= amb == do mb <- fmap amb ma == join (fmap amb ma)
                 mb
```

There you go.